# GWT 2.6.1 and client side BeanValidation JSR-303 and Internationalization i18n

Tags: gwt, internationalization, bean-validation

currently I'm developing a GWT 2.6.1 client-side application.

I'd like to use JSR-303 BeanValidation client-side. Using a custom ValidatorFactory this works fine.

As last step I would like to internationalize (i18n) the validation messages, i.e.

```
public interface User {

/**
 * @return the username
 */
@NotEmpty(message="{user.error.username}")
public String getUsername();

/**
 * @param username the username to set
 */
public void setUsername(String username);

/**
 * @return the password
 */
@NotEmpty(message="{user.error.password}")
public String getPassword();

/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password);

/**
 * @return the remoteServer
 */
@NotEmpty(message="{user.error.remoteserver}")
public String getRemoteServer();

/**
 * @param remoteServer the remoteServer to set
 */
public void setRemoteServer(String remoteServer);

}
```

The Validation is working, but i18n for the errormessages doesn't.

I found some hints using a custom UserValidationMessagesResolver [in the official sources](https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/samples/validation/src/main/java/com/google/gwt/sample/validation/client/CustomValidationMessagesResolver.java), but unfortunately the signature of UserValidationMessagesResolver is different to the signature in GWT 2.6.1 so this example can't be used.

The official GWT documentation seems not to contain any examples (at least I didn't find it).

Is there any working client-side GWT 2.6.1 BeanValidation example using i18n?

Thank you in advance,
Christoph

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your "official sources" link is outdated. GWT sources moved to https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/master/ a while ago. The sample there is known to build.

You can get the sample, ready for use, in the GWT SDK bundle, that you can download at http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html

Comment: Hi Thomas, thanks for your reply. It helped me to fix my issue documented in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Thomas Breuer I was able to solve my issue.

My implementation of UserValidationMessagesResolver looks like this:

```
public class CustomValidationMessagesResolver extends
AbstractValidationMessageResolver implements
UserValidationMessagesResolver {

    protected CustomValidationMessagesResolver() {
    super((ConstantsWithLookup) GWT.create(ValidationMessages.class));
    }

}
```

The ValidationMessages interface in my project is automatically created using the gwt-maven-plugin.

In my activity I create a ValidatorInstance using

```
Validator validator = Validation.buildDefaultValidatorFactory().getValidator();
```

This does not translate the validation messages until the CustomValidationMessageResolver is registered in the .gwt.xml Module description:

```
<replace-with
    class="my.custom..CustomValidationMessagesResolver">
    <when-type-is
        class="com.google.gwt.validation.client.UserValidationMessagesResolver" />
</replace-with>
```

Now everything works like a charm.